# AWS Aurora MySQL / NestJS TypeORM Row level security

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm, amazon-aurora, nestjs-typeorm

I'm trying to come up with some way to have some form of RLS on our API, this hasn't been a problem in the past, but as more and more companies start working together within my webApp, it's become a point of focus for me.  Here is the basic table structure:

```
**companies**
company1
company2
company3

**users**
user1
user2
user3

**data**
company1, specific table data
company2, specific table data
```

And so on.  The problem started when a user needs to see data from more than a single company, but we had to create additional access rules. that table looks something like this:

```
**Relationships**
**user, company, module, access_level**
user1, company1, "data", "full"
user1, company2, "data", "read"
user2, company2, "data", "full"
user2, company2, "data", "update"
```

Then lets say I have an API endpoint that's something like GET /data.  The API knows who my user is, I want it to only return the data that the current user has access to see.  The same would go with create and update permissions and so on.

The two options I've found so far is to either update all of my queries on the API side to do joins across the tables, or to create views based on the users or different possible company combinations and so on.

**The question:**

Are either of these correct?  Are there other methods I should consider?  Is there anything like a standard row level security in TypeOrm as an add in (Since it's not available in aurora mysql)?

Answer (score 0):

If row level security were implemented in the TypeORM or any other client-side method, it would be pretty weak, because code could work around it. It would be an ineffective enforcement.

I can suggest a few other solutions:

### VIEWs

MySQL supports views. You can grant privilege to a given user to query the view, and the view has privilege to query the base table (the user does not have direct privilege on that base table). But built into the definition of the view is a condition that limits what the user can see.

### Separate tables or schemas

You can grant users privilege to query specific table(s), or tables under a schema. Instead of row-level security, just make a separate table for each set of data, and grant each user access to the respective table.

This becomes impractical if users should have access to some overlapping subsets of rows.

### Stored procedures

This is the most flexible if you have a variety of different access policies, because in theory you can code any amount of logic in a procedure. The user can be granted privilege to call a procedure, and the procedure has privilege to query the base tables. So the user can get the data, but only in the manner prescribed by the procedure implementation.

I generally discourage use of stored procedures in MySQL, but for enforcing specialized access, it could be effective.